# Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have been trying to solve this for hours and I have no idea why this is happening. I keep on getting this error when trying to update one of my "Employees" with my GUI that I made.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'test'
```

Whenever I click an employee in my TableView, and then change the field of something, I would get that. Here is a picture of my GUI:

[image: employee records]

Nothing in my data table is a DOUBLE, they all are like this:

[image: mysql data table]

I have googled everywhere and it all says it relates to syntax for my SQL query but that looks fine so I do not know why.

Here is the code for my Update button:

```
public void handleUpdateEmployee(ActionEvent event) {
    String sql = "UPDATE employees set firstName = ?, lastName = ?, gender = ?, age = ?, position = ?, image = ? where employeeNum =?";
    try {
        Integer employeeNum = Integer.valueOf(employeeNumField.getText());
        String firstName = firstNameField.getText();
        String lastName = lastNameField.getText();
        String gender = genderField.getText();
        Integer age = Integer.valueOf(ageField.getText());
        String position = positionField.getText();
        String image = imageField.getText();

        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, employeeNum);
        pst.setString(2, firstName);
        pst.setString(3, lastName);
        pst.setString(4, gender);
        pst.setInt(5, age);
        pst.setString(6, position);
        pst.setString(7, image);

        pst.executeUpdate();
        loadEmployeeData();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help and if you need any more details, let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bound your query parameters in the wrong order.  Look closely at the statement and then the updated code which follows:

```
String sql = "UPDATE employees set firstName = ?, lastName = ?, gender = ?, ";
sql += "age = ?, position = ?, image = ? where employeeNum =?";

pst.setString(1, firstName);  // first parameter (?) in statement
pst.setString(2, lastName);
pst.setString(3, gender);
pst.setInt(4, age);
pst.setString(5, position);
pst.setString(6, image);
pst.setInt(7, employeeNum);   // LAST parameter (?) in statement
```

Comment: Ah! I feel so stupid. Thank you so much! Everything works now :)